# How to get radio button value in SweetAlert with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, sweetalert

I want to use `Sweet Alert` for get radio button value in Angularjs. Is there a way to get selected radio button value. I am using `SweetAlert v1.1.3` anf `ngSweetAlert` directive.

```
SweetAlert.swal({
    title: "Please Select:",
    text: '<form> <div class=""> <input type="radio" name="csvSelect" id="radio1" ng-model="radioValue" ng-value="1" > <label for="radio1"> Whole records </label> </div> <div class=""> <input type="radio" name="csvSelect" id="radio2" ng-model="radioValue" ng-value="2" ng-click="getVal()"> <label for="radio2"> Selected records </label> </div></form>',
    html: true,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Download it!",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: true,
    showLoaderOnConfirm: true
},
function (isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
        SweetAlert.swal("Deleted!", $scope.radioValue, "success");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go - http://jsbin.com/lonotipeba/edit?js,output

I think sweetAlert apply `display:none` to input elements. So sorry for big radio button, you can control with your CSS. When you click on download button then you will see value of radio in a JS alert.

You can pass a `function` in SweetAlert to accomplish your goal.

P.S click on **Run with JS** button to see sweetAlert .

Comment: Is there any way without using jQuery statement `$(...)`

Comment: You can use vanilla JS. Only one line is in jquery, that you can easily change to JS.